# How can I sum matrices in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a closed world (box) of 150 x 150 patches. I have 1 turtle in each patch (I used the "sprout" command). These turtles perform some behaviors and in the end store an energy-left value in their original patch and die. This generates a matrix of this energy-left value. I would like to loop, in order to do 15 repetitions of these same procedures and thus generate 15 matrices with the energy-left values and then make the sum of these 15 matrices and result in the end 1 single matrix with the sum of the energy-left of each patch of 15 repetitions.

I have no idea how I can do this in netlogo. Can anyone help me in any way? I accept suggestions of places where I can get this information etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is really about matrices. It seems to me that what you want is 15 loops of 'create turtles, do tasks, store value' and you want to add the stored values together with the patch defining which ones go together.

You have presented it from the perspective of the turtles but think about it from the perspective of the patches. The patch creates a turtle, has the turtle do some tasks and then the turtle has a final value. The `patch` can remember that value fine even after the turtle dies. So store the values at the patch, summing as you go.